# My hyperlink works but the cursor isn't changing to a pointer

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, mouse-cursor

I've got an intro page with an embedded .SWF file and audio controls (I know, they're not recommended but the client loves the idea!).  I created the .SWF graphically (in Illustrator) not with Adobe Flash.  I was able to locate code to make the .SWF a hyperlink, which works, however the client really wants the cursor to show a hand/pointer so it's an obvious hyperlink to enter their site.

I've tried a variety of CSS, such as:

```
* {cursor: pointer; }
body {cursor: pointer, auto; }
link {cursor: pointer }
a:hover {cursor: pointer }
```

But none of these seem to work!  The mouse will be a pointer on the rest of the page but not when you are over the .SWF object.  Here's my HTML:

```
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0" bgcolor="#000000">

<audio controls autoplay>
<source src="BasketballBeats.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="BasketballBeats.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1440" height="700" onmouseup="document.location='http://www.clientsite.com/welcome'">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.clientsite.com/TBS-Enter-Site-Intro.swf" />
</object>

</body>
```

I've also uploaded a sample of the page using the first CSS I tested, so you can see how the cursor changes above and below the object but not over it!  http://tentendesignstudio.com/staging/test/intro30  Can someone tell me a way to get this to work?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `cursor: pointer;` not `cursor; pointer;`

Comment: Why don't you just create the link inside the SWF?

Comment: Edited my OP to correct the typos in my CSS example code.  pablopixel, I made the .SWF using layers in Adobe Illustrator and exported from there, because I don't have Flash or an .FLA to edit and create the link.

Answer (score 0):

There are some Syntax error

Try this

```
    * {cursor: pointer; }
body {cursor: pointer; }
:link {cursor: pointer; }
a:hover {cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my OP to correct that, those were typos in my post, not the code I tried.  None of those work, either separately or all together.  ;-)  I also added a link to a sample page so you can see how it's behaving (pointer above and below object, but not over it!)

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this in Flash with ActionScript by setting your "ENTER SITE" button (or any movieclip in your flash file for that matter) to:

```
this.mouseEnabled = true;
this.buttonMode = true;
```

I can't give you more specific details on how to add this functionality in your specific case without seeing the actual AS code.